# example of a group without association property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

is there a set with an operation and an identity element ,that every element has a unique inverse , but the operation is not associative?

i think such example works:
$S=\{a,b,e\}$ , $e$ is identity and we define:
$a^2=b^2=e$ , $ab=a$ , $ba=b$

we see $b(ab)=ba=b$ and $(ba)b=b^2=e$.

is it true?

thanks a lot

Comment: This is called a [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup).

Comment: What do you mean "true"?  It is an example of an algebraic object called a loop.  It is not a group, as groups must be associative.  See [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Generalizations) for other such objects.

Comment: @user115608 Your example is correct, however it is not a loop (all loops of order $\leq 4$ are groups).  Your example is an idempotent magma (groupoid).

Comment: @Mark Greer How can I  prove that  all loops of order less than  5 are groups? Thanks

Comment: @user115608 The multiplication (Cayley) table of a loop is a normalized (reduced) [Latin square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).  So simply construct the possible multiplication tables for each order.

Comment: @MarkGreer sorry, I didn't understand you. My example has all the properties of a group except the associativity,so it is a loop.what is wrong with this?

Comment: @user115608 Your example has an identity element, has unique inverses for each element, and is not associative.  However, it is NOT a loop.

Comment: @MarkGreer isn't the associativity the difference between a group and a loop?

Comment: @user115608 Think about it this way: loops + associativity = groups.  Not the other way around (as your example clearly shows).  In a loop, you must be able to uniquely solve $xy=z$ for any $x,y,z$ in your loop.  You have $ae=a=ab$, so there is not a UNIQUE solution to $ax=a$.

Comment: @MarkGreer why"  In a loop, you must be able to uniquely solve xy=zxy=z for any x,y,zx,y,z in your loop. You have ae=a=abae=a=ab, so there is not a UNIQUE solution to ax=aax=a."?

Comment: @user115608 In your example $(ab)a\neq a(ba)$, so your expression isn't well-defined.

Comment: @MarkGreer no it shows that my example fails associativity.

Comment: @user115608 Correct!  I'm just stating that your example is NOT an example of a loop, which was previously stated.

Comment: @MarkGreer Why it is  not a loop?why" In a loop, you must be able to uniquely solve xy=zxy=z for any x,y,zx,y,z in your loop. You have ae=a=abae=a=ab, so there is not a UNIQUE solution to ax=aax=a."?